How to write req guard in Rocket.rs properly?
Im trying to write req guard that will either return user_id: String or just terminate request with Status::Unauthorized
use rocket::async_trait;
use rocket::http::Status;
use rocket::outcome::IntoOutcome;
use rocket::request::{FromRequest, Outcome, Request};

use mongodb::bson::doc;

// modules
use crate::user_module::user_model::UserModel;
use crate::DB;

struct Auth {}

#[async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for Auth {
    type Error = ();

    async fn from_request(req: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<String, ()> {
        let db = DB.get().unwrap();
        let users_collection = db.collection::<UserModel>("users");

        req.cookies()
            .get_private("user_id")
            .and_then(|cookie| cookie.value().parse::<String>().ok())
            .or_forward(Status::Unauthorized)
    }
}

The problem is... it always gives me an error, doesn't matter what i'm changing
Right now, problem is
method `from_request` has an incompatible type for trait
expected signature `fn(&'r rocket::Request<'_>) -> Pin<Box<(dyn std::future::Future<Output = Outcome<guards::Auth::Auth, (Status, ()), Status>> + std::marker::Send + 'async_trait)>>`
   found signature `fn(&'r rocket::Request<'_>) -> Pin<Box<(dyn std::future::Future<Output = Outcome<std::string::String, (Status, ()), Status>> + std::marker::Send + 'async_trait)>>`

and i have no idea what this is about
The guide i found is... idk incomplete? Where is struct?

The error just means you must return a -> Outcome<guards::Auth::Auth, ()> not a -> Outcome<String, ()>

@cafce25 and how to return this? I have no idea or real example =(

Start with fixing your signature, but I can't really help further cause I don't use rocket.

Unfortunately, I found no information on how to force rocket to parse a private cookie here, so here is some working code without parsing cookie's value:
use rocket::async_trait;
use rocket::http::{Cookie, Status};
use rocket::outcome::IntoOutcome;
use rocket::request::{FromRequest, Outcome, Request};

use mongodb::bson::doc;

// modules
use crate::user_module::user_model::UserModel;
use crate::DB;

pub struct Auth {
    pub user_id: String,
}

#[async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for Auth {
    type Error = ();

    async fn from_request(req: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, ()> {
        let db = DB.get().unwrap();
        let users_collection = db.collection::<UserModel>("users");

        let a_cookie = req.cookies().get("a-token");

        // if no such cookie
        if a_cookie.is_none() {
            return Outcome::Forward(Status::Unauthorized);
        }

        // if cookie
        match a_cookie.unwrap().value().parse::<String>() {
            Ok(user_id) => {
                let user_id_verif = /* verify user_id (cuz it was encrypted) */todo!();

                let user: Option<UserModel> = users_collection
                    .find_one(doc! {"user_id": &user_id_verif}, None)
                    .await
                    .expect("Error connecting to DB");
                if user.is_none() {
                    // if no such user
                    Outcome::Forward(Status::Unauthorized)
                } else {
                    Outcome::Success(Auth { user_id })
                }
            }

            // if invalid
            Err(_) => Outcome::Forward(Status::Unauthorized),
        }
    }
}

